# How to find duplicates in a datastructure within a datastructure in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have events in a list within a column of a data frame. I have to find if the gps data (latitude and longitude) are duplicated within the events. Below is my data frame.

| deviceId | insertTime | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 1686261264478 | [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261000937', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436213', 'longitude': '-90.5173831'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261001954', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436203', 'longitude': '-90.5172008'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261002963', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043618', 'longitude': '-90.5169604'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261003971', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436147', 'longitude': '-90.5167171'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261004989', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436122', 'longitude': '-90.5164759'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261006007', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436088', 'longitude': '-90.516233'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261007015', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436047', 'longitude': '-90.5159967'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261008032', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436036', 'longitude': '-90.515768'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261009049', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436022', 'longitude': '-90.5155419'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261010068', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043602', 'longitude': '-90.5153184'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261011083', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436021', 'longitude': '-90.5150956'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261012094', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436028', 'longitude': '-90.5148754'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261013110', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436024', 'longitude': '-90.5146568'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261014120', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436006', 'longitude': '-90.5138385'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261015136', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261016146', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435974', 'longitude': '-90.514005'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261017165', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435972', 'longitude': '-90.51379'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261018172', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435965', 'longitude': '-90.513576'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261019191', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435963', 'longitude': '-90.5133605'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261020209', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435954', 'longitude': '-90.5131474'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261021215', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435946', 'longitude': '-90.5129359'}}] |
| 456789 | 1686261264478 | [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261000937', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436213', 'longitude': '-90.5173831'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261001954', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436203', 'longitude': '-90.5172008'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261002963', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043618', 'longitude': '-90.5169604'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261003971', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436147', 'longitude': '-90.5167171'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261004989', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436122', 'longitude': '-90.5164759'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261006007', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436088', 'longitude': '-90.516233'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261007015', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436047', 'longitude': '-90.5159967'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261008032', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436036', 'longitude': '-90.515768'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261009049', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436022', 'longitude': '-90.5155419'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261010068', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043602', 'longitude': '-90.5153184'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261011083', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436021', 'longitude': '-90.5150956'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261012094', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436028', 'longitude': '-90.5148754'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261013110', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436024', 'longitude': '-90.5146568'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261014120', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436006', 'longitude': '-90.5138385'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261015136', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261016146', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261017165', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435972', 'longitude': '-90.51379'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261018172', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435965', 'longitude': '-90.513576'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261019191', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435963', 'longitude': '-90.5133605'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261020209', 'speedDataModel': {'speed': '70', 'distance': '1'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261021215', 'speedDataModel': {'speed': '60', 'distance': '2'}}] |

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: ....Also mention what you tried and why it failed

Comment: My expected out is deviceId - 456789 gpsDataModel - 2( {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199') is repeated, devicId -12345 gpsDataModel - 1 (no duplicates)

Comment: I tried below code to get the gpsDataModel first and then explode but it did not work. I also tried to                                                         df_records_copy["events"] = df_records_copy["events"].apply(literal_eval)
df_records_copy["gpsDataModel"] = df_records_copy["events"].apply(lambda x: [d["gpsDataModel"] for d in x])
df_records_copy = df_records_copy.explode("gpSDataModel")

Comment: I was not able to get gpsDatModel thru the lambda .

Comment: @sman, but for `deviceId - 456789` the gps entry `{'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}` does not matched with `{'latitude': '38.0435974', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}` by `latitude`, they are only matched by `longitude`. Check your input

Comment: yes I get no duplicates for lat/long combinations in either row

Comment: @sman - sorry there was a typo in the data. fixed it . now u should see duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep connection with `deviceId` we can add new column to the dataframe and search for duplicates with `collections.Counter` + `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def find_gps_dups(events):
    counts = list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] > 1, 
                            Counter([tuple(gps['gpsDataModel'].values())                                            
                            for gps in events if 'gpsDataModel' in gps]).most_common()))
    if not counts:
        return '1 (no duplicates)'
    return counts

df['gpsDataModel'] = df['events'].apply(find_gps_dups)
print(df)
```

---

Sample output:

```
   deviceId                                             events                      gpsDataModel
0   1234567  [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234...                 1 (no duplicates)
1    456789  [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '4567...  [((38.0435985, -90.5142199), 2)]
```

Comment: I am getting below error 
TypeError: string indices must be integers . when i tried to implement your function in my code. If you could explain what its doing, I will debug and see

Comment: I was tring to debug and when i tried the below code got this error  @RomanPerekhrest ```Cell In[111], line 7, in find_gps_dups(events)
      4 def find_gps_dups(events):
      6     for gps in events:
----> 7         print(tuple(gps['eventDateTime']).values())
      8     counts = list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] > 1, Counter([tuple(gps['gpsDataModel'].values()) 
      9                                                          for gps in events]).most_common()))
     10     if not counts:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @sman, I don't have `print(tuple(gps['eventDateTime']).values())` in my code, you have used my code incorrectly. Make sure that `df['events']` contains lists of dicts and apply the above solution, it should work.

Comment: @romanPerekhrest- i added the line to debug it. when i removed the line its the same issue.

Comment: @sman again, make sure that `df['events']` contains lists of dicts

Comment: @RomanPerekHest. i was able to run thru code after converting df['events']. The issue now i am facing is not all the list of dicts have gpsDataModel some gpdDataModel will be replaced by speedDatamodel in the actual dataframe. Updated the dataframein the post with a sample

Comment: @sman, anyway, you need to analyze only dicts with `gpsDataModel` ?

Comment: yes. @RomanPerekHest

Comment: @sman, check my update

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you explain or point to the reference of  tuple function, takewhile and counter function together?

Comment: @sman, `tuple` is a basic builtin data structure, https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile , https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter